# How to get damaged images while displaying it in gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm using a grid view for showing my gallery images, but few of them aren't displaying anything. When i open facebook app and go for image posting, its also showing those blank images, but when i'm trying to select it showing messages "can't read file , it might be damaged."

How would i do this??

```
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                null, null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        count = imagecursor.getCount();
        thumbnails = new Bitmap[count];
        arrPath = new String[count];
        thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            try {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

                arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

                onProgressUpdate(String.valueOf(id));

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

here's the code which i'm using in doInBackground();

Thank you for help.

Comment: Just refresh your gallery items.

Comment: @ Harshit Rathi I did that, but that's not worked, neither in facebook.

Comment: is your gallery display that items correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line for refreshing gallery item pragmatically

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))));
```

it will happening while some files u just delete from sdcard and gallery of android is not updated i.e that time device is not able to fetch that image so u can try with this 
 For images

```
private void getallimages(File dir)
    {

    String[] STAR = { "*" };
    controller.images.clear();

    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    Cursor imagecursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    int count = imagecursor.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();//this is my wrapper class 
        if(new File(imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))).length()<=10485760)
        {
            imageItem.filePath = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

        imageItem.id = id;
        imageItem.selection = false; //newly added item will be selected by default this it do for check box unselect u dont need to fill this 
        controller.images.add(imageItem);//this i just add all info in wrapper class    

        }
} }
```

And if it will not come from this also then just print something for user :)

```
when u try to fetch or open that image then just give one condition like i try to open that image and if it is not present then toast for it that this image might be corrupt or not present in sdcard
```

Comment: I've update my code, when i used your filtering method none of image is showing in grid.

Comment: like u dint got even all valid image also

Comment: whenever u call that method then u have to pass file dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();.... have u pass this path dude

Comment: yes, i've got just blank square and check box.(no imge)

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); have u pass this

Comment: No, i'm not using that yet. can you show me how would i do that.

Comment: then how can u call my method getallimages() dude

Comment: the method i've mentioned above is returning all images..i haven't use your all method

Comment: have  u just add my first line only sendBroadcast ??

Comment: No, yours if condition

Comment: see u can check from your path like whenever u will get any image path from your method then check it like if(Filepath.exists()) then only add in your gridview images wrapper class or anywhere add in which u use to store all file to show in grid